# Rails 3.2 - Why does overriding [] muddle up has_many relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

I'm working on upgrading a legacy Rails app from 3.0 to 3.2, and have run into some really baffling behavior from ActiveRecord. I have two very simple models:

```
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :newsletter_entries

  def [](key)
    # Weird old code, not related to NewsletterEntry
  end

  # etc.
end
```

and

```
class NewsletterEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :newsletter

  # etc.
end
```

In my Rails 3.0 branch, this all works fine. But in my Rails 3.2 branch, for whatever reason, calling newsletter_entries on a newsletter always comes back empty. Looking through the SQL statements, it quickly became apparent that ActiveRecord is always searching  the newsletter_entries table for entries with newsletter_id=NULL, regardless of the actual primary key of the Newsletter I'm handling. Consider the SQL at the end of this console output:

```
> newsletter = Newsletter.create! :title => "Proof of Concept"
### SQL and irrelevant fields omitted
=> #<Newsletter id: 13, title: "Proof of Concept", created_at: "2013-02-28 00:44:25", updated_at: "2013-02-28 00:44:25"> 

> newsletter.newsletter_entries
  NewsletterEntry Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `newsletter_entries`.* FROM `newsletter_entries` WHERE `newsletter_entries`.`newsletter_id` IS NULL
=> []
```

After a lot of wailing and gnashing of teeth I traced the problem back to the custom [] method on the Newsletter model - remove it and everything's back to normal. That override was a code smell to begin with, and I can resolve the problem easily now that I know the source- but the whole affair has left me morbidly curious about the role of [] in ActiveRecord relationships. Can anyone explain to me what exactly went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Newsletter` class inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`, which is defined in `activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb`.

One of included modules inside `class Base` is `AttributeMethods`, which is defined in `activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb`.

And there is method defined:

```
# activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb
def [](attr_name)
  read_attribute(attr_name) { |n| missing_attribute(n, caller) }
end
```

That is where your code breaks Rails code.

How to find this:

- Clone Rails repository.
- Find all `def []`: execute `grep -r 'def \[\]' ./activerecord/`
- Find `class Base`: execute `grep -r 'class Base' ./activerecord/`
- Open this class and compare all `def []` search results with modules included in `class base` (class itself defined near to bottom of `activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb` file.

Comment: That definitely explains what was getting overridden, but it looks like that behavior predates Rails 3. I suppose what I'm really curious about is why the relationships defined by has_many suddenly depend on the Rails-default [] method as of 3.1 or 3.2. That being said, the failure makes a lot more sense in this context- many thanks.

Comment: You can explore changes between branches with this command: `git diff -b origin/3-0-stable origin/3-2-stable ./activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb`